# Why does SwiftUI ForEach<>._layoutChartContent get called here?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I am trying to add a SwiftUI chart inside a SwiftUI sheet. The chart has around 288 data points and around 10 different AreaMarks. When I try to add any of .chartForegroundStyleScale, .chartXAxis, or .chartYAxis view modifiers I start to notice an animation hitch when dismissing the sheet. I set a breakpoint and noticed that when I add any of these modifiers, ForEach<>._layoutChartContent gets called when I dismiss the sheet. So I am guessing the animation hitch happens because the chart's layout is happening at the same time as the sheet dismiss animation. My question is why does SwiftUI ForEach<>._layoutChartContent get called here ONLY when I add these view modifiers? Here is code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var p = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("press") {
                p = true
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $p) {
            Chart {
                ForEach(0...288, id: \.self) { i in
                    AreaMark(
                        x: .value("Time", i),
                        y: .value("Cost", i)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("", "Cost"))
                }
            }
            .chartForegroundStyleScale(["Test": Color.red])
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice the animation hitch when you add around 10 of those AreaMarks.

Comment: SwiftUI is weird - maybe try putting your Chart in its own separate view?

Comment: It is, but I've tried that already.